# Replace text inside a huge multidimensional array

Tags: array, customization

I've a huge multidimensional array with no-way to foreach it :), Anyway, i want to replace all `http` to a keyword so if the client convert his website into `https` he won't change all old images for the new url.

I tried `array_map`, `array_walk` and of course `str_replace` but i found that i must make infinite foreach for every nested array.

```
Array (

[Repeater_1] => Array (

        [1] => Array (
                [user_defined_field_1] => http://Value_1
                [user_defined_field_2] => http://Value_2
            )

        [2] => Array (
                [user_defined_field_1] => http://Value_1
                [user_defined_field_2] => http://Value_2
            )

    )

[Repeater_2] => Array (

        [1] => Array (
                [user_defined_field_3] => http://Value_1
                [user_defined_field_4] => http://Value_2
            )

        [2] => Array (
                [user_defined_field_3] => http://Value_1
                [user_defined_field_4] => http://Value_2
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: if you don't want a loop how would you use it then? I don't think you can just use the data without loop.

Comment: I just ask for an easy way like array_map or array_walk to perform a function to all array items.

Comment: array_map or array_walk still using loop, it just you write less code about it, and the loop is performed by php itself, otherwise there is no way to apply callback function to each of the array value

Comment: is there no way to change the array value for the URL without the protocol? what did you use to generate the data? if you can change the raw data itself, you may use esc_url() later for displaying the url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this php built-in function `array_walk_recursive`

```
function wpse_do_something_on_data() {
   $data = array(
        'repeater-1' => array(
            array(
                'user_defined_field1' => 'http://www.domain-001.com',
                'user_defined_field2' => 'http://www.domain-002.com',
            ),

            array(
                'user_defined_field1' => 'http://www.domain-011.com',
                'user_defined_field2' => 'http://www.domain-012.com',
            ),
        ),

        'repeater-2' => array(
            array(
                'user_defined_field1' => 'http://www.domain-101.com',
                'user_defined_field2' => 'http://www.domain-102.com',
            ),

            array(
                'user_defined_field1' => 'http://www.domain-111.com',
                'user_defined_field2' => 'http://www.domain-112.com',
            ),
        ),
    );

   array_walk_recursive( $data, 'wpse_callback' );

   return $data;
}

function wpse_callback( &$value, $key ) {
   $value = str_replace( 'http://', 'keyword', $value );
}

$my_data = wpse_do_something_on_data();

var_dump( $my_data );
```

Comment: That's what i am talking about, You're my hero, Working like a charm..